# Как оптимизировать программу?

Tags: c#

Написал для себя "программу", но она употребляет 3.4Гб оперативной памяти... Стабильно... 
Функционал такой:

1.Запускаем программу, если есть в БД что-то (текст, дата, изображения) - загружаем в `dataGridView1` (через `Task.Factory.StartNew`).
2.По нажатию на кнопку запускается `Task.Factory.StartNew`, качаются Json'ы и нужные данные заносятся в БД (Около 6000)
3.Параллельно, с БД берется ссылка на изображение (с пункта 2), и оно скачивается в папку, после этого ссылка в БД заменяется на путь где лежит изображение. (Тоже через `Task.Factory.StartNew`)

На данный момент все 6000 картинок (300Мб) лежат в папке и 3.4Гб оперативной памяти употребляется на пункте 1 (не только когда `dataGridView` заполняется, а и когда уже полностю заполнена). Мне не жалко памяти, но считаю что это не правильно.

Буду благодарен за любые советы.

Comment: Во первых, не достаточно данных, что бы что то вам сказать по делу. Но по опыту могу предположить, что вы не реализовали пейджинг, а вытаскиваете все содержимое из бд в вашу таблицу, вместо того, что бы вытаскивать лишь необходимую часть.

Comment: Ну что ж вы хотите, вы грузите в память очень много, вот у вас в памяти и много всего. Если вы пишете на WPF, попробуйте контролы с виртуализацией.

Comment: И база данных — не самое лучшее место для хранения картинок.

Comment: @VladD В базе только путь к картинкам хранится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6000 изображений в базе данных хранятся в полном размере. Но в dataGridView1 они отображаются небольшими, но загружаются целиком. Значит грузите изображение не целиком, а уменьшенные копии и их показывайте в dataGridView1.

Comment: Да и нужно ли сразу все грузить в dataGridView1? Пользователь за раз не больше 100, думаю, сможет увидеть, так что если сделать подгрузку данных по нужде, то сыкономит дофига памяти и времени

Answer (score 2):

Запускаете любой профайлер - смотрите, кто сожрал память.

Если память сожрана нужными вам данными - грустите и оставляете программу в покое.

Если нет - возитесь с очисткой данных, ручной запуск сборщика мусора, очистка ссылок, прочая муть.